# How to use functions and objects in java program that asks for the birthyear, then interpret if the person is a senior citizen or not

Tags: java, function, object

Consider the following:

```
    package senioreligible;
    import java.time.Year;
    import java.util.*;  
    public class SeniorEligible {
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.print("Enter your Year of Birth: ");
    
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int birthYear = in.nextInt();
    
            int age = Year.now().getValue() - birthYear;
    
            System.out.println("Your are " +age+" years old.");
    
            if (age>=60) {
                        System.out.println("You are eligble to be senior citizen.");    
                 } 
            else {
            System.out.println("You are not eligible to be senior citizen.");
    }
    }
    }
```

I have a sample code working but the problem is how to use functions and objects in this syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
  import java.util.*;
   import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
   import java.time.LocalDateTime;

   public class Main
  {
        public static void main (String[]args)
        {
             System.out.print ("Enter your BirthYear-");
            Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
             int birthYear = in.nextInt ();
            LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now ();
             //   System.out.println (now.getYear ());

           int age = now.getYear () - birthYear;

           System.out.println ("Your are " + age + " years old.");

            if (age >= 60)
            {
                  System.out.println ("You are eligble to be senior citizen.");
             }
              else
              {
                  System.out.println ("You are not eligible to be senior citizen.");
             }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Same program with function.

```
        import java.time.LocalDate;
        import java.time.Period;
        import java.util.Scanner;

        public class Main {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.print("Enter your Date of birth-");
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                int birthYear = in.nextInt();
                int birthMonth = in.nextInt();
                int birthDay = in.nextInt();
                calAge(birthYear,birthMonth,birthDay);
            }

            static void calAge(int birthYear,int birthMonth, int birthDay) {
                LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.of(birthYear, birthMonth, birthDay);
                Period p = Period.between(birthday, LocalDate.now());

                System.out.println("Your are " + p.getYears() + " years old.");

                if (p.getYears() >= 60) {
                    System.out.println("You are eligible to be senior citizen.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You are not eligible to be senior citizen.");
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to create a method(function) in the program and create an object of the class in the main method and then call the method of the user-defined class which takes input for the birthyear. The code below is working correctly now.

```
import java.time.Year;
import java.util.*;

 public class SeniorEligible {
   private int birthYear;

   public SeniorEligible() {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter your Year of Birth: ");
      birthYear = sc.nextInt();
      sc.close();
   }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SeniorEligible ob = new SeniorEligible();

    int age = Year.now().getValue() - ob.birthYear;

    System.out.println("Your are " + age + " years old.");

    if (age >= 60) {
        System.out.println("You are eligble to be senior citizen.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("You are not eligible to be senior citizen.");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: @Torben *This discussion is in codereview territory* - definitely agree - will delete my comment.